# Titanium ios build error: The folder “Headers” doesn’t exist

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator, titanium-sdk

I am getting an error while building the titanium app for ios

```
[TRACE] error: The folder “Headers” doesn’t exist. (in target 'Test' from project 
'Test')
[ERROR] ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] The following build commands failed:
[ERROR]         ProcessXCFramework /Users/myuser/Projects/v2-mobile- 
app/modules/iphone/ti.intercom/1.0.0/ti.intercom.xcframework
[ERROR] (1 failure)
```

I tried searching it on the forum but did not resolve it yet. 
I am using SDK version `9.3.2.GA` and xcode 12

Comment: Titanium is kinda dead. Try using other popular alternatives like ReactNative.

Comment: This doesn't help with the question and there is still an active community, PRs to the main repo, an initiative to take over the whole code and webpages after next year and lots of modules are updated and created. Even today. No need to switch to a different platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ti.intercom.xcframework is a static library which has been compiled as an xcframework. Within the framework's directory you'll find the directories for the different platforms the module has been compiled for. Each of these folders is missing the Headers folder (probably lost within git commits), as the Headers directories are empty. Just create empty 'Headers` directories within each platform tree, and add a .gitkeep file to ensure the changes propagate through git.
ti.intercom.xcframework

- ios-arm64

  - Headers (missing, create an empty one)
  - libti.intercom.a
- ios-x86_64-simulator

  - Headers (missing, create an empty one)
  - libti.intercom.a

Answer (score -1):

Trying building with XCode 11.7 instead.

Comment: What is the solution to build with Xcode 12?